# Ubuntu 13.10 Upgrade Failed

Tags: upgrade

I had Ubuntu 13.04 dual booted with Windows 7. I tried to upgrade to 13.10 using the software manager. However after the downloading stage i.e. `Fetching new Packages` my system shutdown somehow and the process was  not complete. After having restarted it I am not able to access my hard drive through Ubuntu and neither am I able to open any applications. When I check the `About this Computer` it says that I have Ubuntu 13.10. I try opening the applications using `Alt-F2` but every application I open crashes after some time.
So is there any way to complete the upgrade process?
I'm new to ubuntu so have very little idea.

Comment: Theoretically your system could be fixed but it will take *time*. If you are willing, you can run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo dpkg -C`, then do `sudo apt-get check`. Edit your question and post the results of each one.

Comment: @Braiam I tried the `dpkg` option using the Recovery Mode, but in vain. Nothing changes. Do I try it now after a normal boot?

Comment: did you made the other ones too? what are the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the method suggested by @braiam above. As I have already mentioned, after I restarted my system I was not able to access any applications. So I used the `Alt+F2` command and then entered `update-manager` in the text box and checked the `Run in Terminal` option. The manager didn't run but I was able to open a new terminal window this way. Then I did what was suggested above and everything was fine.